# How to install PCL for 16.04, PPA not working

Tags: 16.04, ppa

I tried to follow the PPA for the prebuilt binary:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
```

but I get a failure message like:

> W: The repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu
>   xenial Release' does not have a Release file. N: Data from such a
>   repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially
>   dangerous to use. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation
>   and user configuration details. E: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been
>   ignored, or old ones used instead.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the first link in your error message, getting into the `dists` directory, it seems that this PPA does not support Xenial, as there is indeed no such directory.

[This link](https://larrylisky.com/2016/11/03/point-cloud-library-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) however, provides a link to a pre-built DEB file you can download and install using `dpkg` (not recommended as it is just a Dropbox link and the file could contain malicious code) and also explains how to build it from source (recommended as it only installs trusted packages and downloads the code from the official GitHub repository, which can be considered a trusted source).

I have not tested it but as it looks like a standard compile procedure and as mentioned above, downloads the source code from an offical repository, you should be fine following the steps there, given you do not want to install the DEB file which would be perfectly fine, as I would not want to do it, too.

Answer (score 1):

The [PPA you have added](https://launchpad.net/~v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/+archive/ubuntu/pcl) does not contain packages for your release, so you need to remove it first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
```

I have never used PCL, but it is packaged in official repositories (see its [source `pcl` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/pcl)).

The simplest method would be to install the metapackage

> **libpcl1.7**
>      Point Cloud Library -- metapackage

with

```
sudo apt-get install libpcl1.7
```

and use it as you plan to use it :)